# Why must KafkaServer be thread-safe

Tags: apache-kafka

I've been Kafka user for a while and today I have to read its core source code.

Well, I've found that the code about starting a Kafka broker was here: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/server/KafkaServer.scala

In this scala file, there is a function `startup()`, which is invoked when we start a Kafka broker.

What makes me confused is that it seems that some atomic variables are used to keep this function thread-safe. As you can see there are some atomic boolean variables, such as `isShuttingDown`, `startupComplete`, `isStartingUp`.

```
def startup(): Unit = {
    try {
      info("starting")

      if (isShuttingDown.get)
        throw new IllegalStateException("Kafka server is still shutting down, cannot re-start!")

      if (startupComplete.get)
        return

      val canStartup = isStartingUp.compareAndSet(false, true)
      if (canStartup) {
        brokerState.newState(Starting)

        /* setup zookeeper */
        initZkClient(time)
        ...
        ...
```

But I kind of don't know why we need such a thread-safe mechanism. As my understanding, one process of Kafka broker has only one `KafkaServer`, which means that the function `startup` has only one chance to be executed. If we try to start more than one process of Kafka broker in a short period on the same machine, it's just a inter-process issue, instead of multi-threading issue. Thread-safe doesn't seem to be necessary.

Can someone tell me why some atomic variables are used here? Why is thread-safe necessary here?

Comment: what would happen if you send two consecutive shutdown calls to the broker from two different clients(or from the same one), if `isShuttingDown` wasn't atomic?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/cs/race-conditions

Comment: @aran I don't think so. As my understanding, Kafka Server is what it is, there is no any other server which accepts commands to start or shutdown server. To start a Kafka, we can execute the script provided by Kafka: `./bin/kafka-server-start.sh ./config/server.properties`.

Comment: You don't think so, but that's how it works. It's a server. It listens for commands. Do you think that it we both send a command, it will wait until yours is finished, and then start mine? It does not have a synchronous behaviour. When you call www.google.com, do you think the server just waits to execute previous commands, and then show me the page?

Comment: @aran, Kafka broker has registered the `INT` and the `TERM` signals in the main function. So I think sending two consecutive shutdown is OK.

Comment: It is OK because it implements the mechanism to ATOMICALLY check its state. The source code you see , those commands, are called from OUTSIDE of the broker. If two consecutive shutdown commands are called without the boolean being atomic, both commands could see it as false, starting two shutdowns. I repeat, it's a server listening commands from an endpoint.

Comment: @aran It is a server, BUT the function `startup` is about to start the server itself, it has no capability to do any listening thing yet. OK?

Comment: @aran The main function is here: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/Kafka.scala . When it call `kafkaServerStartable.startup()`, the function `startup()` will be invoked, at the moment, the server is just about to be started. It hasn't listened any port yet.

Comment: but YOU are calling it, as I could also call it, by executing kafka-server-start.sh at the same time than you. You are not getting the point here. It receives commands and executes the methods. If the previous called command can't be reflected in consecutive ones, you can't guarantee a broker won't startup twice, or try to shutdown five times!

Comment: @aran  As I said in my question, if you open three terminals and concurrently call `kafka-server-start.sh`, it would be an inter-process issue, instead of multi-threading issue. They are orthogonal. Right?

Comment: @aran I hope you could understand that I'm talking about the issue in a single process, thread-safe is meaningful only if we are talking about in a single process. If you run many times `kafka-server-start.sh`, you will get many processes, which has no business with thread-safe at all.

Comment: IPC is not safe from race conditions. You have the same issue regardless of the kind of mechanism for each specific command. https://examradar.com/interprocess-communication/ That's why you need the variables being Atomic.

Comment: the problem, again, is that this is a server that receives/sends commands to multiple endpoints. That's the root issue here. The broker is a shared resource and hence must be thread safe.

Comment: @aran OMG, the server hasn't finished its start-up procedure, it hasn't have any capability to receive any command. What are you talking about.

Comment: Okay, you win. Tell confluent to change those variables so it ain't atomic anymore, you found a bug. They may reply you with a *what are you talking about*, but don't listen to them; they are the ones that incorrectly made the broker thread safe

Comment: @aran How about you tell me where the receiving/sending component is in Kafka source code

Comment: how about you continue reading until you understand why a broker must be thread safe